# Box2D: can't get b2RevoluteJoint to work properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, box2d

I'm trying to model the behaviour of two bodies connected with a hinge (I'm using `b2RevoluteJoint`) using b2Box. Here's the relative (overlapping) position of two objects at the very beginning.

[image]

Both of them have a red dot (they are at the same global coordinates). I expect the longer object to rotate around this dot. Here's the code (`anchorView` is the small square, `rotorView` is the long stick):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *anchorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 30, 30)];
    anchorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.2];
    UIView *anchorDot = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 13, 4, 4)];
    anchorDot.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:anchorView];
    [anchorView addSubview:anchorDot];

    UIView *rotorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 300, 30)];
    rotorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:0.2];
    UIView *rotorDot = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 13, 4, 4)];
    rotorDot.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:rotorView];
    [rotorView addSubview:rotorDot];

    b2Vec2 gravity; gravity.Set(0.0f, -9.81f);

    world = new b2World(gravity);    
    world->SetContinuousPhysics(true);

    // Static anchor
    b2BodyDef anchor;
    anchor.position.Set(anchorView.center.x / PTM, (1004.0 - anchorView.center.y) / PTM);
    anchor.type = b2_staticBody;    
    b2Body* anchorBody = world->CreateBody(&anchor);

    b2PolygonShape anchorBox;
    anchorBox.SetAsBox(anchorView.frame.size.width / PTM / 2.0, anchorView.frame.size.height / PTM / 2.0);
    anchorBody->CreateFixture(&anchorBox, 0.0);

    // Dynamic rotor
    b2BodyDef rotor;
    rotor.position.Set(rotorView.center.x / PTM, (1004.0 - rotorView.center.y) / PTM);
    rotor.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    b2Body *rotorBody = world->CreateBody(&rotor);

    b2PolygonShape rotorBox;
    rotorBox.SetAsBox(rotorView.frame.size.width / PTM / 2.0, rotorView.frame.size.height / PTM / 2.0);
    rotorBody->CreateFixture(&rotorBox, 0.0);

    rotorView.tag = (int)rotorBody;

    // Joint
    b2RevoluteJointDef jointDef;
    jointDef.Initialize(anchorBody, rotorBody, anchorBody->GetWorldCenter());
    world->CreateJoint(&jointDef);

    // doing stuff
    rotorBody->SetAngularVelocity(5.0);

    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 / 30.0 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:rotorView repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];            
}

- (void)onTimer:(NSTimer *)theTimer {
    int32 velocityIterations = 8;
    int32 positionIterations = 1;

    UIView *rotorView = [theTimer userInfo];
    b2Body *rotorBody = (b2Body *)rotorView.tag;

    world->Step(0.3f / 60.0f, velocityIterations, positionIterations);

    CGFloat angle = rotorBody->GetAngle();
    b2Vec2 c = rotorBody->GetWorldCenter();

    rotorView.center = CGPointMake(c.x * PTM, 1004.0 - c.y * PTM);

    CGAffineTransform rt = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
    rotorView.transform = rt;
}
```

After starting this I'm getting a different type of movement. Here's what it looks like (I added few strokes for clarification):

[image]

More precisely, red dots are not bound together, but the distance between bodies' centers always remains the same, as if there's a rope where I drew the dotted line.

If I look at the `jointDef.localAnchorB` in the debugger, it contains the right coordinate of a red dot within the long stick's coordinate system. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. It was all about these two lines:

```
CGFloat angle = rotorBody->GetAngle();
```

and

```
CGAffineTransform rt = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```

Box2D and Cocoa Touch use different directions for counting the rotation angles, so it must be:

```
CGAffineTransform rt = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-angle);
```